# Dynamic bash associative array keys

Tags: bash

I've been wrestling with this problem for a long time and can't seem to find a working solution.

Suppose I have declared two associative arrays.

```sh
declare -A FOO_ARRAY=(
  [a]="first"
  [b]="second"
  [c]="third"
)

declare -A BAR_ARRAY=(
  [a]="first"
  [b]="second"
  [c]="third"
)
```

I can get a list of keys like so:

```sh
$ echo ${!FOO_ARRAY[@]}
c b a
$ echo ${!BAR_ARRAY[@]}
c b a
```

I can also dynamically deference a key from the array by doing something like this:

```sh
for KEY in FOO BAR
do
  temp="${KEY}_ARRAY[a]"
  echo ${!temp}
done
```

However, if you notice that the operator for dynamically referencing variables is also the same to get the list of keys from an associative array, how could I make something like this possible in order to dynamically list the keys in an associative array?

A naive example like this results in an `invalid variable name` error.

```sh
$ export NAME=foo
$ export temp="\!${NAME^^}_ARRAY[@]"
$ echo ${!temp}
bash: \!FOO_ARRAY[@]: invalid variable name
```

What I'm searching for is a way to dynamically return the list of keys from an associative array as if the above code sample returned:

```sh
c b a
```

Comment: Why are you exporting local variables? Is the uppercase operation relevant? Are the `-rg` flags to `declare` relevant? (See [mre] for reference.)

Comment: To your point, I suppose the `-rg` flags are not necessary, but that is how I am declaring the arrays in my script. I do have a use case for them to be both read-only and global in my script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `nameref`:

```
declare -rgA FOO_ARRAY=(
  [a]="first"
  [b]="second"
  [c]="third"
)

name="foo"
declare -n array="${name^^}_ARRAY"
echo "The keys are: " "${!array[@]}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `declare -n`. From `help declare`:

```
-n  make NAME a reference to the variable named by its value
```

Example:

```
declare -A foo_array=(
  [a]="first"
  [b]="second"
  [c]="third"
)
declare -n temp="foo_array"
echo "${!temp[@]}"  # -> a b c
```

For more details, see `info bash` under the ["Bash Builtins" section](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins).

Comment: Your answer also solves my problem, thank you, but I noticed the response from @that-other-guy first.

Comment: @bkvaluemeal No harm done my friend, and you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

**This Will Work**

```
NAME=foo
temp="${NAME^^}_ARRAY[@]"
echo ${!temp}
```

**Explanation:** here temp will store " FOO_ARRAY[@] " as string only and when echo it in reference way it does print the value.

**Example**

```
declare -rgA FOO_ARRAY=(
  [a]="first"
  [b]="second"
  [c]="third"
)

declare -rgA BAR_ARRAY=(
  [a]="first"
  [b]="second"
  [c]="third"
)

echo ${!FOO_ARRAY[@]}
echo ${!BAR_ARRAY[@]}

for KEY in FOO BAR
do
  temp="${KEY}_ARRAY[a]"
  echo ${!temp}
done

NAME=foo
temp="${NAME^^}_ARRAY[@]"
echo ${!temp}
```

Run:

```
a b c
a b c
first
first
first second third
```

Comment: this is a correct way to list the values in the associative array, but I'm looking for a way to dynamically list the keys in the array (`a b c`).